# How would i go about making a script to deleate one file type from multiple folders

Tags: powershell

My issue is that I am trying to make a PowerShell script to delete a particular file. I need to remove all .JPEG files from multiple folders that are all in the same path. I am wondering if I would be able to use a loop to go into each file and delete the file type, and then restart and move to the next file until all
.jpeg are removed.

my idea was to use

Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\downloads' *.jpeg | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }

I just am not able to figure out how to get the script to go into the sub files in this path.

any help would be really apricated

Comment: If you want to look into all folder inside `E:\downloads` you can add `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: `Remove-Item` accepts piped input. `Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\downloads' -Filter '*.jpeg' -Recurse | Remove-Item`